# How to speed up clearing filters from control

Tags: c#

I am using custom grid and i have created 50 columns with 10000 record. I am trying the below code to clear the filter and its work fine but it will take too much of time so is there any other way to reduce the time.
My tried code is below;

```
 foreach (var Column in datagrid.TextColumns)
            {
                Column.Filters.Clear(); // remove filters
            }
```

Comment: What is that `datagrid` type ? Custom grid derived from?

Comment: datagrid is the control like msdatagrid

Comment: Inherited from which control ? Is it written in managed code? give more info to get help

Comment: it is devexpress control..

Comment: Need more info pls. What is the control name? Namespace? Which platform Winform? Asp? Wpf?

Comment: am using WPF and i have used that devexpress datadrid. i would like to clear the filter when button click so i tried my code but it is working fine but its take too much of time so is there any-other way to reduce the filter...

Answer (score 0):

I can not help you with that little information, my best guest is that you every time you clear the filter, the layout will re-render (and you know how painful it can be)

Try to wrap the clear filter function within [Control.SuspendLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout.aspx) and Control.ResumeLayout, to see if it helps.